# How can I apply a class to a PHP line?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, themes

I have `<?php get_header(); ?>` for the header
and want to add in `class="sticky"` so that when it's parsed to HTML it will read `<header class=sticky">`

Where/how would I do this? Various places I've tried within the PHP line gives me an error message **`**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '?' in /home2//public_html/wp-content/themes/conf-theme/page.php on line 1**`**

Comment: you should edit the header.php template file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the header.php file and add the sticky class to

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
```

The [get_header](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header) function

> Includes the header.php template file from your current theme's directory.

EDIT
jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("header").addClass("sticky");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Howlin, so I can't do any of this in the page.php? I don't want to change the main header attributes, just the header for page.php.

Comment: You can add it with jquery, other than that I don't think so.